# How to set the origin of coordinates properly in R?

Tags: r

How can i  set the origin of coordinates properly in R?
i want the origin of coordinates in my graph,
where `x=1` and `y=-1` not in common  `x=0` and `y=0` ,please see the attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should note that R, by default, puts the axes at the side of the plot, not necessarily crossing at [0;0].

What you can do is plotting the graph without axes and add them up later at the desired position using the `axis` function

```
x <- -5:5
y <- x

plot(x,y, t="l", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
axis(1, pos=-1)
axis(2, pos=1, las=1)
```

See `?axis` for more information (you may find the `at` and `labels` parameters of `axis` particularly useful).

Comment: it should be :`axis(1, pos=-1)` and `axis(2, pos=1, las=1) `

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: oh, yeah, I did not see the crossing on your figure correctly.